# Sorting array-list of objects

Tags: javascript, xml

Wanted to sort the data presented using comparative method but I can't seem to find a way to do that. I'm new to Java and so far, I'm not able to do that effectively. I only know bubble sort and it doesn't seem to function rpoperly whe trying to sort the information that the activity displays on the screen after the user presses on the button "Enter"/

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
int quantity = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_field);
    String name = nameField.getText().toString();

    // Figure out if the user wants whipped cream topping
    CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
    boolean hasWhippedCream = whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();

    // Figure out if the user wants chocolate topping
    CheckBox chocolateCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chocolate_checkbox);
    boolean hasChocolate = chocolateCheckBox.isChecked();

    // Calculate the price
    int price = calculatePrice(hasWhippedCream, hasChocolate);

    // Display the order summary on the screen
    String message = createOrderSummary(name, price, hasWhippedCream, hasChocolate);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); //Only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Just Java order for " + name);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

/**
 * Calculates the price of the order.
 * @param addhasChocolate whether or not the user wants chocolate
 * @param addWhippedCream  whether or not the user wants whipped cream
 */
private int calculatePrice(boolean addWhippedCream, boolean addhasChocolate)
{
    int basePrice = 5;

    if (addWhippedCream) {
        basePrice = basePrice + 1;
    }

    if (addhasChocolate) {
        basePrice = basePrice + 2;
    }
    return quantity * basePrice;
}

/**
 * Create summary of the order.
 *
 * @param price           of the order
 * @param addWhippedCream is whether or not to add whipped cream to the coffee
 * @param addChocolate    is whether or not to add chocolate to the coffee
 * @return text summary
 */
private String createOrderSummary(String name, int price, boolean addWhippedCream, boolean addChocolate) {
    String priceMessage = "Name: " + name;
    priceMessage += "\nAdd whipped cream? " + addWhippedCream;
    priceMessage += "\nAdd chocolate? " + addChocolate;
    priceMessage += "\nQuantity: " + quantity;
    priceMessage += "\nTotal: $" + price;
    priceMessage += "\nThank you!";
    return priceMessage;
}


/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
private void displayQuantity(int numberOfCoffees) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + numberOfCoffees);
}


/**
 * This increments the order number
 * @param view shows the view
 */
public void increment(View view) {
    if (quantity == 100) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You cannot have more than 100 coffees", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    quantity++;
    displayQuantity(quantity);
}

/**
 * This decrements the order number
 * @param view shows the view
 */
public void decrement(View view) {
    if (quantity ==1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You cannot have less than 1 coffee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    quantity--;
    displayQuantity(quantity);
}
```

}

Comment: What you want is a way of sorting your arrayList using certain fields depending if you are in in HotelsActivity and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Comparator` like this.

```
  Collections.sort(mList, new Comparator<Item>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Item palaceOrderModel, Item t1) {
                return palaceOrderModel.getPlaceName().compareTo(t1.getPlaceName());
            }
        });
```

Use above code after adding data to your list.

Comment: Yup it works now just fine, every activity has it's array sorted once i put that code below the array-list on each of the 3 activities. However, just a quick question, now that it's sorted and all 3 activities share the same arraylist, how can I check a specific index of an array-list? Say, I want to know what's on the second index of the arraylist